# What’s the recommended way to set the site URL?

Tags: url, best-practice

There are multiple ways to set the site URL. What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As of Craft 2, **you should be using the new [siteUrl](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#siteurl) config setting**.

---

There are two advantages to setting your site URL using this config setting.

First, The value can be set on a **per-locale basis**, in a way where Craft is actually aware of all locales’ URLs on every request (unlike the [`CRAFT_SITE_URL`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/php-constants#craft-site-url) constant, where Craft only knows the current locale’s URL). That’s a good thing because it means you can easily link to entries’ URLs across different locales, for example.

```
return array(

    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_us' => 'http://example.com/',
        'de'    => 'http://example.com/de/',
    ),

    // ...

);
```

Its value can also be set directly on a **[per-environment basis](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs)**. (Yes you can achieve this using the [`environmentVariables`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables) config setting combined with a `{siteUrl}` tag inside the Site URL setting within the CP’s general settings, but that’s much less direct/obvious.)

```
return array(

    '.dev' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://example.dev/',
        // ...
    ),

    '.com' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://example.com/',
        // ...
    ),

    // ...
);
```

Those of course can be combined as well:

```
return array(

    '.dev' => array(
        'siteUrl' => array(
            'en_us' => 'http://example.dev/',
            'de'    => 'http://example.dev/de/',
        ),
        // ...
    ),

    '.com' => array(
        'siteUrl' => array(
            'en_us' => 'http://example.com/',
            'de'    => 'http://example.com/de/',
        ),
        // ...
    ),

    // ...

);
```

Comment: I just switched over to setting siteUrl this way, but it seems like the variable doesn't get parsed anymore in the asset sources? Here is what my config looks like: https://gist.github.com/davist11/aea165a093b20e159782

Comment: If you want to use a `{siteUrl}` tag in your asset source settings, you will still need to define a `'siteUrl'` key in your [environmentVariables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables) array. That may change in the future though, since it would be handy.

Comment: What value should be entered in the CP General Settings `Site URL` field when using the `siteUrl` config setting?

Comment: @MarionNewlevant if the siteUrl config setting is set, the CP setting is irrelevant.

Comment: It's worth noting that for security reasons you should not set siteUrl dynamically with HTTP_HOST https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/http-host-and-server-name-security-issues