# How can I set dynamic absolute Asset URLs?

Tags: assets, config

I'm working on my first subfolder-based Craft site, so I'm relying on Asset URLs based on the `{{ siteUrl }}` variable. I cannot, however, manage to get them working. Any tags I add to the URL field in the control panel get printed literally (not parsed) in the template output.

My config.php looks like this:

```
return array(

    '*' => array(
    ),

    'foo.craft.dev' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://foo.craft.dev/',
        'devMode' => true
    ),

    'foo.bar.com' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://foo.bar.com/',
        'devMode' => true
    ),

    'example.com' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://example.com/foo',
        'devMode' => false
    ),

);
```

My Logos Asset settings look like this:

[image]

And a relevant chunk of template looks like this:

```
<div class="logos">
    {% for logo in logos.logoImages %}
        <a href="{{ logo.websiteUrl }}" target="_blank" style="background-image: url({{ logo.geturl() }}); padding-top: {{ logo.getHeight() }}px; width: {{ logo.getWidth() }}px;">{{ logo.companyName }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The `background-image` URL above renders out as `{siteUrl}assets/logos/logo.gif`, which isn't parsed as I would expect.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use the {siteUrl} tag in your Asset source settings, you'll still additionally need to define it in your [environment variables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables) as well.

See [here as well](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/920/what-s-the-recommended-way-to-set-the-site-url/921#comment1751_921).

Comment: Ohhhhhh. And here I thought I was already doing that. Turns out I need an actual `'environmentVariables' => array( 'siteUrl' => 'http://whatever.com/' )`. Matt 0, RTFM +1. Thanks Brad.