# $craftPath multiple enviroments

Tags: config, variable, craft-features

I am new to Craft and am trying to figure out what the best way to set the `$craftPath` PHP variable to something like the other configurations for multi-environments.

Locally I have it set up the preferred way, but on my remote server, it's nested an extra level deep in folders (sub domains).

Is there a way to have the variable be set using the same functionality that Craft uses to determine environments? Or do I have to just manually change the value where the index.php lives.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really nice [multi-environment configuration](http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/273) method defined on the craft cookbook website, that creates a global php variable called `CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT` in your main `index.php`. It seems to me that you could also use this global to define the `$craftPath`.

```
switch (CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT) {
    case "dev":
        $craftPath = '../craft';
        break;
    case "stage":
        $craftPath = '../../craft';
        break;
    default:
        // default "production"
        $craftPath = '../../craft';
}
```

I generally use the above method (without the new switch part) in combination with [this configuration method](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-to-set-up-siteurl-to-work-with-both-http-and-https/4734?s=1%7C0.1884#4734) in my `general.php` config file.