# .getUrl() outputting {{ siteUrl }} in address

Tags: matrix, globals

I haven't used Craft in a while now and I have just revisited it, I'm trying to output an image URL from a global matrix field like so:

```
{% for block in globalName.matrixField %}

    {% if block.type == "blockType1" %}

        {% set image = block.blockType1.first() %}

        <a href="{{ image.getUrl() }}">link</a>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

But it keeps outputting as: `{{ siteUrl }}/resources/images/my-image.jpg` (instead of actually outputting the website URL).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your putting the variable in the craft settings input, try wrapping it in single brackets like `{siteUrl}` instead of `{{ siteUrl }}`

That should do the trick

Comment: Sorry, forgot to come back here when I fixed it, yeah this was partially the problem, I was trying to do this through my asset sources too (then realised I could just reference them relative). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're defining your siteUrl as an environment variable?

Try setting it as the actual [siteUrl config setting](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl), rather than a [siteUrl environment variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables).

See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/920/what-s-the-recommended-way-to-set-the-site-url/921#921) for an explanation.

Comment: Yeah I did have it set up as an environment variable (And I am able to output the website url using {{ siteUrl }} so that's working fine) ... but I added in the config setting too and that hasn't made a difference. The link still appears as `<a href="{{ siteUrl }}/resources/images/image.jpg">link</a>`

Comment: When you added the config setting, did you remove the environment variable?