# Environment Variable siteURL ignored

Tags: config, control-panel, siteurl

In my general.php file I have a siteUrl environment variable declared:

```
'ontherocks.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'siteUrl'  => 'http://local.ontherocks.dev/',
    )      
),

'dev.livesite.com' => array(

    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'siteUrl'  => 'http://dev.livesite.com/',
    )       
)
```

But when calling it on my page to get page url: siteUrl ~ entry.url
siteUrl is appearing as it is defined in the Craft CMS General Settings SiteUrl.
Is it possible for the environment variable to take precedence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Control Panel, go to **Settings > General**.

Then set your Site URL to `{siteUrl}`.

This will parse out the `siteUrl` environment variable. For more information, see [this thread...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/913/45)