# multi-environment config for {siteURL} not working

Tags: url, multi-environment, siteurl

I've got a multi-environment setup working well for my database - that was easy to setup and i've had no issues getting it to work. Now i'm trying to set the siteUrl as a multi-config variable and no luck. I have this in general.php

```
return array(

  '.dev' => array(
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'siteUrl'  => 'http://mysite.dev:8888',
    )
  ),
  '.org' => array(
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'siteUrl'  => 'http://mysite.org',
    )
  )

);
```

and i've set "Site URL" in settings > General Settings to {siteUrl}

the problem is, now when I load the front-end of my site, it is outputting my links with {siteURL} written out as the actual links, eg

```
<a href="{siteUrl}/about#start">
```

All the documentation and posts I can find seem to imply that this is all I should have to do. Any idea what's missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Environment Variable siteURL ignored](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/environment-variable-siteurl-ignored)

Answer (score 5):

Multi-environment configs **require** you to create a `'*'` config array, even if it’s empty because there aren’t any config settings that you need to set globally. Simply having that `'*'` array is how Craft is able to determine that this is a multi-environment config, as opposed to `'.dev'` and `'.org'` just being normal config settings. (See the warning on http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs.)

So this should work for you:

```php
<?php

return array(

    '*' => array(
        // It's OK if this is empty, as long as it's here.
    ),

    '.dev' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl'  => 'http://mysite.dev:8888',
        )
    ),

    '.org' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl'  => 'http://mysite.org',
        )
    )
);
```