# Environment specific siteUrl settings not working

Tags: config, siteurl

I followed the advice from [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/multi-environment-config-for-siteurl-not-working/2433#2433) and [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/environment-variable-siteurl-ignored) post, but I just can't get my environment specific `siteUrl`s to work.

This is what my config file looks like:

```
return array(

    '*' => array(
      'errorTemplatePrefix' => "pages/",
    ),

    '.dev' => array(
      'environmentVariables' => array(
        'userSessionDuration' => false,
        'devMode' => true,
        'siteUrl ' => 'http://myurl.dev',
      )
    ),

    '.com' => array(
      'environmentVariables' => array(
        'userSessionDuration' => false,
        'devMode' => true,
        'siteUrl ' => 'http://myurl.com',
      )
    ),

    '.org' => array(
      'environmentVariables' => array(
        'siteUrl'  => 'http://myurl.org',
      )
    )
);
```

These **do not take precedence** over any URL specified in `Settings > General` in the CP as outlined in the docs. If I set the `Site URL` field to `{siteUrl}` in the CP, then my links are broken and look like this: `{siteUrl}/link-to-a-page`.

Am I missing something else to get the `siteUrl` settings to work?

---

### Update

Fixed the additional space in 'siteUrl ', thanks to Lindsey.

My config settings now look like this:

```
'*' => array(
  'errorTemplatePrefix' => "pages/",
),
// local
'.dev' => array(
  'devMode' => true,
  'userSessionDuration' => false,
  'environmentVariables' => array(
    'siteUrl' => 'http://myurl.dev',
  )
),
// staging
'.com' => array(
  'devMode' => true,
  'userSessionDuration' => false,
  'environmentVariables' => array(
    'siteUrl' => 'http://myurl.com',
  )
),
// live
'.org' => array(
  'environmentVariables' => array(
    'siteUrl'  => 'http://myurl.org',
  )
)
```

With this and adding `{siteUrl}` in the CP, everything works as expected - hooray!

It does however not reflect what the Craft docs say, as they state that the config settings "**will take precedence over the Site URL setting in Settings → General**". I've contacted the Craft team to let them know about this.

---

### Update #2

Got this response from Brandon:

> “I'm guessing that when you added 'siteUrl' to your config, you put it inside the environmentVariables array? (which would explain why adding {siteUrl} to the CP setting made it work.)
>
> When the documentation is referring to the siteUrl config setting, it's referring to an actual top-level config setting, not some custom "siteUrl" environmentVariable that happens to have the same name.”

So I've taken the setting out of `environmentVariables`, and hey presto, it all works as expected. You even get a helpful message in the CP:

[image: screenshot]

Final working code:

```
'*' => array(
  'errorTemplatePrefix' => "pages/",
),
// local
'.dev' => array(
  'devMode' => true,
  'userSessionDuration' => false,
  'siteUrl' => 'http://myurl.dev',
),
// staging
'.com' => array(
  'devMode' => true,
  'userSessionDuration' => false,
  'siteUrl' => 'http://myurl.com',
),
// live
'.org' => array(
  'siteUrl'  => 'http://myurl.org',
)
```

Got there in the end - phew!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you change `.dev`, `.com`, etc. to reflect your actual environment URLs. They operate based on a partial string match, so as long as your URL contains one of those substrings, it'll pick up the first one it matches.

For example:

```
'local.mywebsite' => array(
  'environmentVariables' => array(
    'userSessionDuration' => false,
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl ' => 'http://local.mywebsite',
  )
),

'mywebsite.com' => array(
  'environmentVariables' => array(
    'userSessionDuration' => false,
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl ' => 'http://mywebsite.com',
  )
),
```

---

**UPDATE**

Whoa, I think I may have just realized what the problem is... I copied my example from your original code, and copied a glitch right along with it...

You've listed `siteUrl` like this:

```
    'siteUrl ' => 'http://mywebsite.com'
```

Notice anything? There is *an extra space* between `siteUrl` and the closing quote.

```
    'siteUrl '
```

... should be:

```
    'siteUrl'
```

Comment: Thank you Lindsey with the eagle eyes! Words cannot express how much of a n00b I feel right now... That’s got it working. However, the documentation states that the config settings **take precedence over the Site URL setting in Settings → General**, which is not the case. Whatever URL is put there is used, unless you put `{siteUrl}` in the field. I'll let the guys at Craft know about that.

Comment: Oooooh. Easy mistake to make. Those key names could perhaps be trimmed when Craft is going over them, eh?

Answer (score 2):

As of Craft 2.2, you should now be using the new siteUrl setting. [See this reply](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/920/what-s-the-recommended-way-to-set-the-site-url/921#921) for more details.

Your variable siteUrl from environmentVariables should still work, though.

What do you see if you add this to a test template?

```
<pre>
  {{ dump(craft.config.get('environmentVariables')) }}
</pre>
```

Check out [How is the Site URL determined?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/site-url) from the docs as well.

Comment: I get this: `array(1) { ["siteUrl "]=> string(30) "http://mysite.dev" }`

Comment: The post you link to was answered by Brandon on the 8th July. The first post I link to and followed was answered by Brandon on the 8th September, so technically what I've got should be working right? Hmpf.

Comment: Well, environmentVariables in the Site URL setting works in my installations. What version are you on? You should send a support ticket through the support widget, with database-dump. Perhaps something fishy is going on. Either way, I suggest you go for the siteUrl config option instead, which is the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks @fred, turns out I was being a n00b and need better glasses ;)

Comment: We all need some strong glasses from time to time ;)

Comment: Great tip to use `{{ dump(craft.config.get('environmentVariables')) }}`